# Reducing multi-column xts to single column xts based on provided column indexes

Tags: r, xts

I have an xts object with multiple columns of the same type. I have another xts object with integers that correspond to column positions in the first object. I would like to generate an third xts object that contains one column representing the value of the column indicated by the corresponding index. For example:

```
# xts.1:
2003-07-30 17:00:00 0.2015173 0.10159303 0.19244332 0.08138396
2003-08-28 17:00:00 0.1890154 0.06889412 0.12700216 0.04631253
2003-09-29 17:00:00 0.1336947 0.08023267 0.09167604 0.02376319
2003-10-30 16:00:00 0.1713496 0.13324238 0.11427968 0.05946272

# xts.2:
2003-07-30 17:00:00 1
2003-08-28 17:00:00 4
2003-09-29 17:00:00 2
2003-10-30 16:00:00 3

# Desired result:
2003-07-30 17:00:00 0.2015173
2003-08-28 17:00:00 0.04631253
2003-09-29 17:00:00 0.08023267
2003-10-30 16:00:00 0.11427968
```

I feel like I'm missing something very elementary about how to do this but, if so, it's escaping me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data appear to be monthly, so I would strongly recommend you move from a `POSIXct` index to a `Date` or `yearmon` index.  Otherwise you may run into issues with timezones and daylight saving time.

One way to solve this problem is to merge `xts.1` and `xts.2`, then loop over all the rows of the resulting object, subsetting the column by the `xts.2` column in the merged data.

Since your data are monthly, you can loop over all the observations with `apply.monthly`.

```
> xts.3 <- merge(xts.1,xts.2)
> apply.monthly(xts.3, function(x) x[,x$xts.2])
                          [,1]
2003-07-30 17:00:00 0.20151730
2003-08-28 17:00:00 0.04631253
2003-09-29 17:00:00 0.08023267
2003-10-30 16:00:00 0.11427968
```

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks! It feels clunky to do it this way though. You'd think there would be something more elegant and direct.

Comment: @neverfox: there's likely a more elegant solution to your larger problem, but that would require you to back up a few steps before you create the `xts.2` object.